# GitHub Actions Bumping Release Versions

Tags: git, scala, sbt, semantic-versioning

I'm using GitHub actions to build and release my application. I'm using annotated tag for doing releases and uploading packages. This works fine, but I would like to know about how I can keep the versions as an external file and inject them into my build file when I do a git tag. So here is what I do right now, when I want to tag a release:

```
git tag -a v2.2.2 -m "Your comments" // Create annotated tag

git push origin --tags               // Push annotated tag
```

This builds the package with the version 2.2.2, but how can I make this version to reflect in my build.sbt file where I have the version manually set? Inmy build.sbt, I have the following:

```
val module1Version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
val module2Version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: Use something like GitVersion and manually create/update that file as part of the pipeline

Comment: Ok, do you have an example?

Comment: no, never done that for GitHub Actions - search google and you'll probably find parts to put together.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dynver could be interesting for you

Comment: See how we do it with Reliza Hub (I'm working on the product) here - for the helm chart here - https://github.com/relizaio/rebom/blob/master/.github/workflows/github_actions.yml - line 216 and below, specifically line 284 for the sed command and commit. More context on versioning and how to set this up here - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/